# Recaptcha Translations

Tags: javascript, captcha, recaptcha

I am trying to use reCAPTCHA.net's captcha service, however I would like to use the custom translations (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization#i18n) as the built in ones do not cover all the languages.  Also, rather than using one of their standard themes, I would like to go completely custom to match the captcha's look to my site.

Below is a snippet of what I am trying, however for some funny reason it is not working (text remaining in English rather than translated).  I was wondering whether the text links like "Get another Captcha", "Get an audio Captcha", "Help", etc would translate.  If I am understanding correctly, these should translate, depending on the strings I set in the custom_translations attribute.  Also, in case I replace the contents of the text links with an icon instead of text, would the icons get the ALT tag with the appropriate content automatically?

So, for example, if I change this:

```
<div class="recaptcha_only_if_image"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('audio')">Get an audio CAPTCHA</a></div>
```

To this, would the alt tags of the image be prefilled automatically so that when you hover over the icon it says "Get an audio captcha"?

```
<div class="recaptcha_only_if_image"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('audio')"><img height="16" width="16" src="audio.gif" alt="" /></a></div>
```

I am asking this question as when I tried to chose one of the standard themes, such as `theme : 'red', the alt tags were being translated automatically depending on the language.

Here is a snippet of my code.  I have removed my public key from the below.

**JS**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var RecaptchaOptions = {
            custom_translations : {
                    instructions_visual : "Scrivi le due parole:",
                    instructions_audio : "Trascrivi ci\u00f2 che senti:",
                    play_again : "Riascolta la traccia audio",
                    cant_hear_this : "Scarica la traccia in formato MP3",
                    visual_challenge : "Modalit\u00e0 visiva",
                    audio_challenge : "Modalit\u00e0 auditiva",
                    refresh_btn : "Chiedi due nuove parole",
                    help_btn : "Aiuto",
                    incorrect_try_again : "Scorretto. Riprova.",
            },
            lang : 'it', // Unavailable while writing this code (just for audio challenge)
            theme : 'custom', // Make sure there is no trailing ',' at the end of the RecaptchaOptions dictionary
      custom_theme_widget: 'recaptcha_widget'
    };
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="recaptcha_widget" style="display:none">

<div id="recaptcha_image"></div>
<div class="recaptcha_only_if_incorrect_sol" style="color:red">Incorrect please try again</div>

<span class="recaptcha_only_if_image">Enter the words above:</span>
<span class="recaptcha_only_if_audio">Enter the numbers you hear:</span>

<input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field" />

<div><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()">Get another CAPTCHA</a></div>
<div class="recaptcha_only_if_image"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('audio')">Get an audio CAPTCHA</a></div>
<div class="recaptcha_only_if_audio"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('image')">Get an image CAPTCHA</a></div>

<div><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.showhelp()">Help</a></div>

</div>

 <script type="text/javascript"
src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=MY_PUBLIC_KEY">
 </script>
 <noscript>
 <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=MY_PUBLIC_KEY"
    height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
 <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
 </textarea>
 <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
    value="manual_challenge">
 </noscript>
```

I am also attaching a screenshot of the result.
[image]

Comment: where are the javascript functions?

Comment: @AlexRuhl, which javascript functions are you exactly refering to?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the `custom_translations` JavaScript object will not be used if you use your own HTML template. In that case, you would have to manually translate using the same localization as the rest of your app uses. `custom_translations` is used if you do not provide HTML yourself, and instead use one of the predefined themes.